# Unbound value length on mergesort algorithm

Tags: ocaml, mergesort

I have the following task:

> Complete the algorithm
>
> ```
> let rec mergeSort (a, i, b, j, c, k) =
>  if i = (length a) && j = (length b) || k = (length c) then 
>    ()
>  else if i = (length a) then 
>    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
>     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j+1, c, k+1))
>  else if j = (length b) then 
>    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
>     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
>  else if a.(i) < b.(j) then 
>    ...
>  else 
>    ...
> ```

where I suppose the answer would be:

```
let rec mergeSort (a, i, b, j, c, k) =
  if i = (length a) && j = (length b) || k = (length c) then 
    ()
  else if i = (length a) then 
    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j+1, c, k+1))
  else if j = (length b) then 
    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
  else if a.(i) < b.(j) then 
    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
  else 
    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
     mergeSort (a, i, b, j+1, c, k+1))
```

So that it gives the in- and output as follows:

```
let a = [|1; 4; 7; 9|];;
let b = [|2; 3; 4; 5; 6|];;
let c = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]

mergesort(a, 0, b, 0, c, 0) ->
[|1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7; 9; 0; 0; 0|]
```

However, I am getting an `unbound value length` error on the first line. I thought length was a part of the ocaml-library and the part of the error is the actual task, not the answer. How would I change this so that the function compiles?

Comment: Do you intend to use `List.length` or `Array.length` ?? Also, it would be better to mention where is this code being executed!!!

Comment: Edit, I misinterpreted your question. The input and output is now given and as I understand it, this should call the Array.length function.

Comment: `length` is not `Array.length`. Functions are not automatically brought into scope automatically based on type or anything else. You have to explicitly either qualify it (recommended) or bring it into scope using `open` in order to use it unqualified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, the name `length` has to come from somewhere. Given that you're working with arrays, you almost certainly want `Array.length`. You could prepend your code with `open Array` but that's perhaps an overreaction.

You could also bind the name `length` to `Array.length` with `let length = Array.length`.

You could modify your code to explicitly specify which `length` you want:

```
let rec mergeSort (a, i, b, j, c, k) =
  if i = (Array.length a) && j = (Array.length b) || k = (Array.length c) then 
    ()
  else if i = (Array.length a) then 
    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j+1, c, k+1))
  else if j = (Array.length b) then 
    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
  else if a.(i) < b.(j) then 
    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
  else 
    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
     mergeSort (a, i, b, j+1, c, k+1))
```

But I might be more inclined to bind names for the length of each array, and only locally open `Array`.

```
let rec mergeSort (a, i, b, j, c, k) =
  let a_len, b_len, c_len = Array.(length a, length b, length c) in
  if i = a_len && j = b_len || k = c_len then 
    ()
  else if i = a_len then 
    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j+1, c, k+1))
  else if j = b_len then 
    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
  else if a.(i) < b.(j) then 
    (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
     mergeSort (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
  else 
    (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
     mergeSort (a, i, b, j+1, c, k+1))
```

---

As an aside:

```
let c = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
```

Could be:

```
let c = Array.init 10 (fun _ -> 0)
```

And it doesn't feel very idiomatic to have your function mutate that array as an existing value and return unit. It would feel more idiomatic to have `mergeSort` return a merged, sorted array. We can actually use your existing code as a baseline local function. We'll rename it to `mergeSort'`.

```
let mergeSort (a, i, b, j) =
  let c = Array.(init (length a + length b) (fun _ -> 0)) in
  let rec mergeSort' (a, i, b, j, c, k) =
    let a_len, b_len, c_len = Array.(length a, length b, length c) in
    if i = a_len && j = b_len || k = c_len then 
      ()
    else if i = a_len then 
      (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
       mergeSort' (a, i+1, b, j+1, c, k+1))
    else if j = b_len then 
      (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
       mergeSort' (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
    else if a.(i) < b.(j) then 
      (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
       mergeSort' (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
    else 
      (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
       mergeSort' (a, i, b, j+1, c, k+1))
  in
  mergeSort' (a, i, b, j, c, 0);
  c
```

Now:

```
utop # mergeSort(a, 0, b, 0);;
- : int array = [|1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7; 9|]
```

Heck, we can even make it simpler than that by hiding the `i` and `j`.

```
let a = [|1; 4; 7; 9|]
let b = [|2; 3; 4; 5; 6|]
let c = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]


let mergeSort (a, b) =
  let c = Array.(init (length a + length b) (fun _ -> 0)) in
  let rec mergeSort' (a, i, b, j, c, k) =
    let a_len, b_len, c_len = Array.(length a, length b, length c) in
    if i = a_len && j = b_len || k = c_len then 
      ()
    else if i = a_len then 
      (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
       mergeSort' (a, i+1, b, j+1, c, k+1))
    else if j = b_len then 
      (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
       mergeSort' (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
    else if a.(i) < b.(j) then 
      (c.(k) <- a.(i); 
       mergeSort' (a, i+1, b, j, c, k+1))
    else 
      (c.(k) <- b.(j); 
       mergeSort' (a, i, b, j+1, c, k+1))
  in
  mergeSort' (a, 0, b, 0, c, 0);
  c
```

And use it like so:

```
utop # mergeSort (a, b);;
- : int array = [|1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7; 9|]
```

---

Lets optimize that a bit more and curry the arguments:

```
let a = [|1; 4; 7; 9|]
let b = [|2; 3; 4; 5; 6|]

let mergeSort a b =
  let (a_len, b_len) = Array.(length a, length b) in
  let c_len = a_len + b_len in
  let c = Array.init c_len (fun _ -> 0) in
  let rec append x i k =
    if k = c_len
    then ()
    else (k -> c.(k) <- x.(i); append x (i + 1) (k + 1))
  in
  let rec mergeSort' i j =
    if i = a_len
    then append b j (i + j)
    else if j = b_len
    then append a i (i + j)
    else
      let (i', j') =
        if a.(i) < b.(j)
        then (c.(i + j) <- a.(i); (i+1, j))
        else (c.(i + j) <- b.(j); (i, j+1))
      in
        mergesort' i' j'
  in
  mergeSort' 0 0;
  c
```

Comment: I am aware of this. However, everything aside from the “…” was given in the task and the task was only to fill in the blank. Therefore, I didn’t bother with making things simpler or more elegant. Thanks for good tips though!

Answer (score 1):

This is so much simpler if you do it with lists:

```
# let mergeSort a b =
    let rec mergeSort' ?(acc=[]) = function
      | ([], []) -> List.rev acc
      | (a, []) -> List.rev_append acc a 
      | ([], b) -> List.rev_append acc b 
      | ((x::xs as a), (y::ys as b)) ->
        if x < y
        then mergeSort' ~acc:(x::acc) (xs, b)
        else mergeSort' ~acc:(y::acc) (a, ys)
    in
    Array.of_list (mergeSort' (Array.to_list a, Array.to_list b));;

val mergeSort : 'a array -> 'a array -> 'a array = <fun>

# let a = [|1; 4; 7; 9|]
  let b = [|2; 3; 4; 5; 6|]
  let c = mergeSort a b;;

val a : int array = [|1; 4; 7; 9|]
val b : int array = [|2; 3; 4; 5; 6|]
val c : int array = [|1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7; 9|]
```

Comment: I find myself somewhat puzzled by the number of homework questions asked with the OCaml tag that require the use of arrays and imperative programming techniques. Is this really a common practice in courses that utilize OCaml? If so, it seems rather like missing the point.